# useFakeTimers not working in jest/testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm rendering an element that makes use of a setTimeout to change the inner text from a loading state to a desired message:

```js
function Message({ message }: any) {
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const CTATimer = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowMessage(true);
    }, 1500);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(CTATimer);
    };
  }, []);

  if (!showMessage) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>{message.text}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The corresponding test renders, then advances time by 1500ms, and then should show the message. However, currently the test fails and the terminal shows that the text is still `Loading...`. The test is written like so:

```js
const mockMessage = {
  text: "this is a message",
  answers: [],
  id: 1,
};

afterEach(() => {
  jest.useRealTimers();
});

it("should show message after setTimeout", () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1500);
  customRender(<Message message={mockMessage} />); // my customRender is just the default render but with a ThemeProvider wrapper.
  const message = screen.getByText(/this is a message/i);
  expect(message).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Why would my test still be rendering the loading state when 1500ms have passed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should advance timers after rendering the component. Besides, you should call `jest.advanceTimersByTime()` inside [act](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#act) function. Otherwise, it will throws an warning: `Warning: An update to Message inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function Message({ message }: any) {
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const CTATimer = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowMessage(true);
    }, 1500);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(CTATimer);
    };
  }, []);

  if (!showMessage) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>{message.text}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { Message } from './';

describe('Message', () => {
  const mockMessage = {
    text: 'this is a message',
    answers: [],
    id: 1,
  };

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  it('should show message after setTimeout', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    render(<Message message={mockMessage} />);
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(1500);
    });
    const message = screen.getByText(/this is a message/i);
    expect(message).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71174071/index.test.tsx (9.705 s)
  Message
    ✓ should show message after setTimeout (27 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.903 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Comment: This is the right answer, thank you so much. Annoyingly, I'm still really confused as to when to use `act`. rtl claims that that it's not needed: "(All renders and events being fired are wrapped in act, so you don't really need this.)[https://testing-library.com/docs/preact-testing-library/api/#act]"

Comment: Edit to my above comment:
rtl claims that it doesn't do much: "https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#act" https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#act. So I really don't understand when it's necessary.

(previously I was using the wrong link)

Comment: @crevulus you don't need to use `act` when you use rtl utilities, but if you use a jest utility like `advanceTimersByTime` then you should use `act`

Answer (score 7):

If working with an asynchronous test because you need to use `userEvent` for typing etc. I found a solution on this blog: https://onestepcode.com/testing-library-user-event-with-fake-timers/

The trick is to set the `delay` option on the `userEvent` to `null`.

```
const user = userEvent.setup({ delay: null });
```

Here is a full test case

```
test("Pressing the button hides the text (fake timers)", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup({ delay: null });
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    
    render(<Demo />);

    const button = screen.getByRole("button");
    await user.click(button);

    act(() => {
        jest.runAllTimers();
    });

    const text = screen.queryByText("Hello World!");
    expect(text).not.toBeInTheDocument();

    jest.useRealTimers();
});
```

Comment: thanks, this should be bumped for anyone who's using the `@testing-library/user-event`

Comment: this had me scratching my head for hours, until finding this answer, thank you!